# Implement pagination in MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Im working on a list project, and can't seem to implement pagination in my project.
I've tried different solutions I've found on google, but couldn't get it to work. I do not have much experience with C# or MVC projects at all, this is my first project.

Could anyone help me?

This is my Model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
public class funnwpweb01
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Domenenavn")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "IP-Adresse")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string IP { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Server")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Server { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Opprettet")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pris")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required]
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Plattform")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Platform { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Firma")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Firm { get; set; }
 }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
public class Funnwpweb01Controller : Controller
{
    private readonly FunnWebsitesContext _context;

    public Funnwpweb01Controller(FunnWebsitesContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: funnwpweb01
    // Requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string server, string search, string platform)
    {
        // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
        IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Listings
                                        orderby m.Server
                                        select m.Server;

        var funnwpweb01 = from m in _context.Listings
                     select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            funnwpweb01 = funnwpweb01.Where(s => s.Domain.Contains(search));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(server))
        {
            funnwpweb01 = funnwpweb01.Where(x => x.Server == server);
        }


        var movieGenreVM = new DomainServerViewModel();
        movieGenreVM.servers = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());
        movieGenreVM.funnwpweb01 = await funnwpweb01.ToListAsync();

        return View(movieGenreVM);
    }

    // GET: funnwpweb01/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var funnwpweb01 = await _context.Listings
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (funnwpweb01 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(funnwpweb01);
    }

    // GET: funnwpweb01/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: funnwpweb01/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Domain,IP,Server,Start_Date,Price,Platform,Firm")] funnwpweb01 funnwpweb01)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(funnwpweb01);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(funnwpweb01);
    }

    // GET: funnwpweb01/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var funnwpweb01 = await _context.Listings.FindAsync(id);
        if (funnwpweb01 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(funnwpweb01);
    }

    // POST: funnwpweb01/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Domain,IP,Server,Start_Date,Price,Platform,Firm")] funnwpweb01 funnwpweb01)
    {
        if (id != funnwpweb01.ID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(funnwpweb01);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!Funnwpweb01Exists(funnwpweb01.ID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(funnwpweb01);
    }

    // GET: funnwpweb01/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var funnwpweb01 = await _context.Listings
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (funnwpweb01 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(funnwpweb01);
    }

    // POST: funnwpweb01/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var funnwpweb01 = await _context.Listings.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Listings.Remove(funnwpweb01);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool Funnwpweb01Exists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Listings.Any(e => e.ID == id);
    }
}
}
```

And this is my view:

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.DomainServerViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Funn Webhotell";
}

<h2>Funn Webhotell</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Opprett ny</a>
</p>
<form asp-controller="funnwpweb01" asp-action="Index">
    <p>
        IP/Server: <select asp-for="Server" asp-items="Model.servers">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>
        Domenenavn: <input type="text" name="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="15%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.funnwpweb01[0].Firm)
            </th>
            <th width="15%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.funnwpweb01[0].Domain)
            </th>
            <th width="15%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.funnwpweb01[0].IP)
            </th>
            <th width="15%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.funnwpweb01[0].Server)
            </th>
            <th width="10%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.funnwpweb01[0].Start_Date)
            </th>
            <th width="10%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.funnwpweb01[0].Price)
            </th>
            <th width="10%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.funnwpweb01[0].Platform)
            </th>
            <th width="10%">
                Detaljer
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.funnwpweb01)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firm)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Domain)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Domain)</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IP)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Server)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Start_Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Platform)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Endre</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Detaljer</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Slett</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can return your result based on the request params and as params please pass size and pageIndex. Based on these values you can skip and take the list values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List does not contain a definition for 'ToPagedList'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948499/list-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-topagedlist)

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc OtherWise you could implement jquery datatable which is easiest way to implement pagination into datagrid please follow this instruction https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: You have show a whole lot of irrelevant code here, but have not explained what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

See this Gist - https://gist.github.com/McKabue/8ecc676b871b33114dc6d2c3e055b900
Usage: Call this extention **`list.Paging(numberOfResults: 20, page: 2, pageNumbersCount: 5)`** on any **`IEnumerable`** and you get a *`PagedObject`* with the following properties:

```
HasNext         (bool)
HasPrevious     (bool)
Next            (int)
PagedResults    (IEnumerable<T>)
PageNumbers     (List<PagedObjectPages>)
Pages           (int)
Previous        (int)
Total           (int)
Last            (int)
First           (int)
HasFirst        (bool)
HasLast         (bool)
```

==================================================================

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Pager
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Pages the specified items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="items">The items.</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfResults">The number of results.</param>
    /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static PagedObject<T> Paging<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int numberOfResults, int page = 1, int pageNumbersCount = 10)
    {
        page = Math.Max(1, page);
        int itemCount = items.Count();
        float pages = numberOfResults >= itemCount || numberOfResults == 0 ? 1 : ((float)itemCount / (float)numberOfResults);
        int _pages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(pages));

        var _return = numberOfResults >= itemCount ? items : page > _pages ? items.Reverse().Take(numberOfResults).Reverse() : items.Skip(((page - 1) * numberOfResults)).Take(numberOfResults);

        return CreatePagedObjects(page, pageNumbersCount, itemCount, _pages, _return);

    }

    private static PagedObject<T> CreatePagedObjects<T>(int page, int pageNumbersCount, int itemCount, int pages, IEnumerable<T> result)
    {
        int _page = page;
        int _pageNumbersCount = pageNumbersCount;
        int _itemCount = itemCount;
        int _pages = pages;
        var _result = result.ToList();
        var _pageNumbers = GetPages(_pages, _page, _pageNumbersCount);
        int _lastPageNumber = _pageNumbers?.LastOrDefault()?.Page ?? _pages;
        int _firstPageNumber = _pageNumbers?.FirstOrDefault()?.Page ?? 1;

        return new PagedObject<T>
        {
            PagedResults = _result,
            Pages = _pages,
            PageNumbers = _pageNumbers,
            Next = _page < _pages ? (1 + _page) : _pages,
            HasNext = _page < _pages,
            Previous = (_pages > 1 && _page > 1) ? (-1 + _page) : 1,
            HasPrevious = (_pages > 1 && _page > 1),
            Last = _pages,
            HasLast = _lastPageNumber < _pages,
            First = 1,
            HasFirst = _firstPageNumber > 1,
            Total = _itemCount
        };
    }

    private static List<PagedObjectPages> GetPages(int pages, int current, int pageNumbersCount)
    {
        var _pages = new List<PagedObjectPages>();
        if (pages > 1)
        {
            int firstHalfPageNumbersCount = pageNumbersCount / 2;
            int secondHalfPageNumbersCount = pageNumbersCount - firstHalfPageNumbersCount - 1;

            int _start = Math.Max(1, (current - firstHalfPageNumbersCount));
            int _last = Math.Min(pages, (current + secondHalfPageNumbersCount));

            _start = Math.Max(1, (_start - (secondHalfPageNumbersCount - (_last - current))));

            for (int i = _start; i <= pages && _pages.Count < pageNumbersCount; i++)
                _pages.Add(new PagedObjectPages { Page = i, IsCurrent = current == i ? true : false });
        }

        return _pages;
    }

    public class PagedObjectPages
    {
        public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
        public int Page { get; set; }
    }

    public class PagedObject<T>
    {
        public bool HasNext { get; set; }
        public bool HasPrevious { get; set; }
        public int Next { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<T> PagedResults { get; set; }
        public List<PagedObjectPages> PageNumbers { get; set; }
        public int Pages { get; set; }
        public int Previous { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public int Last { get; set; }
        public int First { get; set; }
        public bool HasFirst { get; set; }
        public bool HasLast { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination will be much easier if you use any third party Grids like Jquery datatables, Dev express Grid, Kendo Grid.