# How to increase performance of a process which loads products list from database with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET Web API and there is ProductsController in it. And also there is GetProducts() method to load all products from database. Normally, I load all records at once to return. But I don't think that it is good idea. Because if there will be more than thousand records it will take more time to load them.
My question is: How can I increase performance and decrease time for this operation? 
P.S.: I have 1 table and 9 columns in it.

Thanks very much for your attention.

My question is not about any error.

Comment: yout either implement pagination, so When calling the method you only load X entries of the table starting at index Y (you can use linq Take(X) and linq Skip(Y) for this. Other way is to implement a cache functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain it more? :) I'm not very good at this.. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List does not contain a definition for 'ToPagedList'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948499/list-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-topagedlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of methods, on mentioned in the comments is to implement pagination.

You also mentioned you have 9 columns, so only selecting the columns you need requests instead of all of them.

Assuming you're using an ORM like Entity Framework, the biggest mistake I see is where people call ToList() on a DbSet... which is the easiest trap to fall in out of anything else, as calling ToList() prior to paging will mean the operations you define on the entities thereafter will be performed in memory as opposed to it executing as a SQL statement. So thing like .Skip() ,Take() or your Where clauses should all occur before executing your query by calling ToList().